# Optimizing/reducing geolocation data for speeding up visualization

Tags: geolocation, optimization

I have an application that receives geolocation data from clients (cars) every minute and shows this on a web page (like owntracks). The data is stored simply in an SQL database - 1 point is 1 row, and the display is also similarly simple, all points are shown for the queried period.

My main objective is simple: I need to collect and visualize the location of the clients. The current 1 minute data collection frequency is sufficient.

However, as more and more data gets collected, this is becoming frustratingly slow on the query side. Due to the amount of data collected, it is not even possible to show data spanning multiple days, therefore I am looking at some optimization measures, that would reduce possibly the granularity of the data, but enable visualization of longer periods quicker.

I am not sure however which of the following measures I should follow:

1. Optimize data as it is received, i.e. do not store data points that are not (significantly) different from previous data points. Some of the clients are quite stationary yet transmit data every minute, therefore this could eliminate the storage of this redundant data, albeit at the cost of losing some valuable information as well (e.g. if I only store the first point for a given location, I cannot retrieve later how much time was spent by the client at that location).
2. Store all incoming data, optimize regularly, e.g. by running a map-reduce job every hour that would eliminate duplicate data points and possibly optimize others e.g. with the Douglas-Peucker algorithm.
3. Store and keep all incoming data and optimize upon query, similarly as to point (2). I suspect this would slow down the queries to an unacceptable extent.

Can you suggest the best approach and/or alternative measures? I would be also happy to consider moving to a different storage mechanism instead of SQL, if that could help with this.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Too much data resulting from your queries or the queries themselves being slow on the database side? How exactly do you visualise things in the end? What do you *need* as result?

Comment: I am visualizing on a web page on a map. As there is too much data for a given period, both the backend response time is too slow and also the javascript rendering on the web page takes too long. Result should be a scrollable/zoomable map that shows the locations of the clients for a (preferably longer) period of time.